# Visual Studio 2019 Installer Projects - Old application version installed issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer

I am using [Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) in order to create an installer for my app developed in C#. I changed the source code, saved the project and used `Rebuild` on both the C# app and the installer, but it seems the latter still installs the old app version, since I cannot see the changes I have made after uninstalling and installing my program.

I have tried modifying the `Version` property of the installer, generated new `ProductCode` and even `UpgradeCode` for the project and I also tried changing the app's `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` but neither of these changes made the installer install the new app version, even after several Rebuild commands - it looks like the installer has access to the app version before the changes, but no access to the new version.

What can be source of the above issue?

Comment: When releasing an new version you should only increase the version and generate a new ProductCode. 

UpgradeCode represents a related set of products. A set of different versions of your application will have the same UpgradeCode. This enables newer versions of your application to search and upgrade previous versions installed on the same computer.

Regarding the app installation, does the new version works as expected on a machine that has no previos version installed?

Comment: @J.Tribbiani Unfortunately no, regardless of previous installation conditions the installer installs an old version of the app. I tried deleting the Setup.exe and Setup.msi files but it still looks like that the Build command for the Setup does literally nothing, since nothing happens. I suspect this is an error on the extension side so I will abandon using Installer Projects and move on to WiX.

Comment: if you have a hard time with the WiX, you can always go  with a commercial tool, most of them have the VS Extension in their freeware edition (no license required). It's up to you how much time you want to invest in the installer creation.

Comment: [You can ask the author about it.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects&ssr=false#qna)